# JavaFX: Difference between Popup and PopupControl

Tags: java, javafx, popup, javafx-8

I looked at the API and noticed that there are two popup classes `Popup` and `PopupControl`, and both of them extends `PopupWindow` (i.e. these two controls are siblings in the inheritance chart).

I need to display a popup, but now I have no idea which would be more suitable. What exactly are their differences?

The first impression is that `PopupControl` has more functions, so is there any reason to choose `Popup` over `PopupControl`?

Comment: Isn't the difference that `PopupControl` is styleable via CSS, while `Popup` is not?

Comment: @James_D That is the only difference?

Comment: Hmm. As far as I can tell (it also has size properties, similar to region, but I suspect that that's a consequence of some of the CSS properties it supports). Weirdly, though, the properties are not listed in the CSS documentation. FWIW context menus use `PopupControl`, so my guess would be that is the one appropriate for what you're doing... Just a guess, really, though.